# Restricted input sequence of a latch

Tags: flipflop, latch

Suppose you have this circuit diagram,[image]
I do not understand my professor's lecture. My professor said that AB equal 10 is restricted as when it is changed to 01, it would cause q to be either 1 or 0 depending on the delay of the circuit elements. Could you clarify how such thing happen. After consulting the textbook, this is what it says:

> "AB = 01 is a hold input combination,  AB = 00 and 10 are reset input combinations, and  AB = 11 is a set input combination.   This is reset dominant latch where S =  A  and R = B'.    P  = Q' + B'.   In each stable state P  = Q' even for the input combination AB = 10 (SR = 11) so P  is usable as  Q'.
>   Allowing the input combination  AB = 10 (SR = 11) would result in unreliable operation if both  A  and B could change at the same time, i.e., change to  AB = 01 (SR = 00), because the latch could end up in either state  0  or  1  depending  upon  the  delays  in  the  circuit."

Comment: A logic signal consists of more than one door is passed with delay. When you compared with source logic you got an `condition`. Every IC got transition time (mean delay), maybe microseconds, nanoseconds, picoseconds etc. Shortly  trick `Compare with results before using logic signal`, detect rising/falling edge, check pattern, make an output... But be careful on `rising/falling,logic signal duty` always  need`delay_logic_duty > transition time`.

Answer (score 1):

This transition is illegal and simultaneous changing inputs causes a "race condition" or "metastable".  If you recognize the dual gates as an SR LATCH ( *or simple asynchronous Set/Reset Flipflop* )  with active low inputs then a negative glitch may cause a different output result.
[image]

In general it depends on rise time, prop delay, setup, hold time of any device.

Comment: Can you please explain more how the glitch would happen? Thanks!

Comment: If A going low is slower than B going high both inputs are high momentarily and NAND out is low which forces a SET on Q. Otherwsie if B is slower there is no glitch.  Generally these are prevented by gating input signals with a clock for synchronous changes and a forced race or only changing one input at a time by stagger clocks driving A,B. or some other arrangement all together.  These are "asynchronous operations" so race conditions must be avoided here. These delays can occur due to trace capacitance (rise time) and length prop delay in nanoseconds).

Comment: I think it is a lot clearer to refer to that as an SR latch, not SR flip flop.  An SR flip flop, which does exist, is two gated SR latches back to back with opposite polarity clocks (master-slave): http://www.play-hookey.com/digital/sequential/rs_nand_flip-flop.html

Comment: I agree , my slack terminology, corrected, although in theory , registers, memory state logic , flip flops and latches are synonyms with specific use making differences